# AS3, clarification on the 'this' pointer

Tags: actionscript-3, this

I am writing a program in flex, and I am having an issue with the this pointer.

I have a function call inside of a function and I am wondering which event my this pointer is passing.

```
private function funcA(someArgument)
{
    newDialog.show("Title", "Body", funcB, this) // the 'this' is the argument for funcB
}

private function funcB(CloseEvent:event)
{
   if(event == Event.CANCEL)
      doStuff;
   if(event == Event.COMPLETE)
      doOtherStuff;
}
```

To clarify, my question is, when I pass the this pointer into the function in the newDialog, am I passing my newly created Dialogue or am I passing in funcA.  I'm thinking and hoping its the former.

I would just test this manually but the system is really large and currently tied in with other events so its difficult for me to just instantiate objects to test them.

Comment: You are passing in the scope/class instance where this code is contained.

Comment: `CloseEvent:event` looks like it should be `event:CloseEvent`

Comment: OP probably comes form C# or similar.

Answer (score 1):

While null is correct, the method signature on `funcB` looks like it should be added as an event listener. `funcB` is expecting an event. All events have a property `target`, which is the actual object that dispatched the event, and `currentTarget`, which is the object that was being listened to. These will only be different in the case of bubbling events on the display list, where a child object really dispatched the event.

If the Class you found this code in is not a subclass of Event, I would expect funcB to error pretty hard. If it is a subclass of Event, it shouldn't be, because the functionality in `funcA` is nothing that should ever be the responsibility of an event.

Answer (score 0):

> when I pass the this pointer into the function in the newDialog, am I passing my newly created Dialogue or am I passing in funcA.

Neither one.

You have a `private function`, which is a member of a `class`. In order to call that `function`, an object has to be created that's an instance of that `class` and then `funcA` can be called on that object.

**`this` is a reference to exactly that object.**